# Characteristic polynomial without determinant in Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading *Linear Algebra Done Right* these days. I noticed that the author first defines characteristic polynomials for linear operators $T:V \to V$, where $V$ is a complex vector space. Then the author defines characteristic polynomials for linear operators $T:V \to V$, where $V$ is a real vector space, as the characteristic polynomials of their complexifications.

Now I am curious about the generalisation of the approach by looking at arbitrary fields. We can replace the field of complex numbers with an algebraically closed field. But what should we do to the field of real numbers?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. You describe how the author defines the characteristic polynomial over a real vector space, but then you ask "but what should we do to the field of real numebrs?" Are you asking for some alternative method of defining the characteristic polynomial that avoids complexifications?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question. There are two fields discussed in the book, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. I think $\mathbb{C}$ in the book can be replaced by any algebraically closed field. But if $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by any field, how can one define the characteristic polynomials?

Comment: That makes sense. The answer I provided gives one approach. Alternatively, it turns out that every field has an [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure), which allows us to take the same approach.

Comment: @BenGrossmann The approach that Axler adopts is that he first defines the characteristic polynomials when the underlying vector space is complex. Then he introduces the complexification of real vector spaces, and defines the characteristic polynomial of the linear operator as the characteristic polynomial of its complexification. If we copy the approach, then we first have the characteristic polynomials if the field is algebraically closed. What is the alternative for complexification?

Comment: We could use the most general version of "complexification", namely an [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh Great! Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146559/discussion-between-inbrevi-and-ben-grossmann).

Answer (score 1):

One approach to defining the characteristic polynomials without field-closures is to use the [structure theorem for modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) or the corresponding [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form). The characteristic polynomial can be defined as the product of the [invariant factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor) of $\Bbb F[T]$.

Alternatively, we could extend Axler's approach for defining the characteristic polynomial to arbitrary fields by using the [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) (in the way that the complex numbers are used relative to the reals) and [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars) (in the way that complexification is used for real vector spaces).